# Index cells that contain time above 2:00

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a great idea in my head for a dashboard project in g sheet, however, with my limited knowledge I'm having trouble to assemble the proper formulas to actualize it.

**I want to check a vertical range of cells. If the cell contains time above 2:00, index the cell in column **1**, Otherwise, write "No tours".** (All the cells in the range contain value **""**)

[The table and the needed results marked with green on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha4Ht.png) 
In the following example, I want him to index me A13,A24,A28

Since I couldn't solve the first problem, I haven't integrated hlookup yet.

I would be really glad if you could help me to figure out how to properly approach this issue.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: you said "I want to check a horizontal range of cells", then posted an imgur link to a picture of a vertical range of cells.

Comment: @MattKing Hey thank you for mentioning, I should've posted a whole picture of the table and what exactly I've meant - edited: now you can see the whole table and the required results.

Comment: `=INDEX(A1:A30;SMALL(IF(I1:I30<>"";ROW(A1:A30);"");row(1:30)))`

My next attempt was also a failure, I found an add-on that solves my issue, but I rather to understand the formula myself than use external tools.

Comment: I think the OP is coming from excel and is using INDEX() differently than a Sheets user would?

Comment: Shavlen, if you are, in fact, using Excel and not Google Sheets, please change the tags on your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need this:

`=IFERROR( FILTER(A:A, I:I >= TIME(2,0,0) ), "No Tours")`

Comment: Sorry Erik, but it doesn't seem to work as I intended, it filters the whole column instead of indicating only cells with time above 2:00

Comment: `=INDEX(A1:A30, SMALL(IF(I1:I30<>"", MATCH(ROW(I1:I30), ROW(I1:I30)),""),rows(A1)))` Also doesn't work, it only prints the smallest value, instead of indexing 3 of them

Comment: I think the OP is coming from excel and is using INDEX() differently than a Sheets user would?

Comment: I am using g sheet, but maybe different formulas from the internet got mixed up in the process, but it shouldn't matter that much right?

Comment: Shavlen, it does matter. And keep in mind that we don't have access to your sheet, data or data types. All of these matter. If you'd like, share a link to your sheet. Then one of us can easily offer a working formula.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for?

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,I:I>2/24),"No Tours")
```